# Reason for fewer answers on my questions

Tags: discussion

What could be the major reason for not receiving many answers on the questions I ask here? Is it the technology my questions are based on or my questions are confusing? Can there be a way I can improve my questions so as to receive most of the response?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: More answers is not necessarily better answers.  Getting one answer that clears it right up is preferably to a sea of people weighing in on all sorts of things that don't really solve the problem.  Your goal should be to create posts that people find useful (which they indicate with voting), and that generate either useful debate/discussion, or an answer that truly addresses the original question.  If you get one answer but its a good one, then your question served a useful purpose (to you and possibly others).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are my observations about your questions:

- [Exception handling in groovy server pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508906/exception-handling-in-groovy-server-pages) (3 years ago):

  You didn't provide any feedback to the answerers, so no one will know if the answers solved your problem or not. If the answers do not solve your problem, you should provide feedback so that answerers can provide you with more or deeper clues based on your response. *@Alidad* asked you to provide an example, offering you a chance to look at your code and help, but you didn't reply.
- [Elasticsearch : Disable IDF completely for search result scoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226293/elasticsearch-disable-idf-completely-for-search-result-scoring) (1 year and 3 months ago):

  You didn't provide any feedback to the answerer. *@Peter Dixon-Moses*'s answer looks fairly straight forward (to me at least), but you didn't address his answer, so I assume that it solved your problem.

You want more answers, but you aren't doing anything to signal that the existing answers do not solve your problem. If an answer doesn't work for you, you need to provide feedback on the answers, clarify miscommunication, and provide as many details as you can. If people post comments asking for clarifications, provide those clarifying details.

Comment: thats a superb piece of advice, will stick to this from now. Thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 5):

For example this question could be improved by linking to examples of your previous questions. That would make your question *specific*. Now it's vague.

Comment: Thanks, thats a very good suggestion. I will edit my question